# C# Typed Dataset corrupts CommandText

Tags: c#, strongly-typed-dataset

I need to perform some maintenance on an old C# Windows Forms application (.net 3.5) that is using typed datasets. To this purpuse I'm bound to using VS 2010.

The issue is as follows, when I just 'touch' a typed dataset, or simply after some rebuilds, the CommandText within the datasets designer file is getting corrupted. Automatically CR+LF and whitespaces are being placed, e.g.

```
this._adapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "\r\n                      dbo.NameOfAStoredProcedure\r\n                    ";
```

When performing a search/replace to get rid of this unwanted changes, it works for a short while and then the issue reoccurs.

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue and how to fix this?

Comment: A work around might be to create the adapter in code (not with the Designer tool).

Comment: That would be a nice last resort if I'm not able to solve the designer issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it is corrupted? It should have no effect on the behavior.

Anyways, this is exactly the output you expect when you embed text in XML. Eg:

```
<CommandText>
  dbo.NameOfAStoredProcedure
</CommandText>
```

If you are pedantic about the whitespace (that should be ignored), just do the following:

```
<CommandText>dbo.NameOfAStoredProcedure</CommandText>
```

Comment: Believe me, the tableadapter is not able to execute the sp like this.

Comment: Could not find stored procedure '
                      dbo.NameOfAStoredProcedure
                    '. Please note the whitespace before and after the procedure name...

Comment: OK, I just tested it and get the same (whitespace/newline in the C# string) when having it on multiple lines. The problem is with your XML as shown. It works like you want it to if everything is on one line. If it still changes, so auto formatter might be interfering. If you still cant solve it, the write some code to trim the command text string when the app starts.

Comment: Now I also removed the whitespaces from the .xsd file like you mentioned before. Now it seems to leave the designer.cs in tact. I'll give it a couple of more runs, just to see if it will stay like this and then its good enough for me. Thank you!

Comment: I think something might be editing the xsd file's text or formatting it.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the file and regenrating the deleted file.

Just create another file and copy paste the same contents. and delete the previous one.

Make sure you do a back up ! Good luck

Comment: I created a new Typed Dataset. Copy/pasted the tables / adapters back in, but no luck.